# Insert data and Login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an assignment in laravel where I've an Application form. I want to submit application form with email, mobileNo, customerId etc.

What I want is to insert form data into users table and then user will be logged in with auto generated password and redirect to Customer's dashboard. Where will be a modal will be open and ask for add password.

On the other hand there is also a login page from where user can login as usual. The login functionality is working properly.

Can someone help me to achieve the above functionality. Thanks in advance.

**Data is : **

email='user@gmail.com'

mobile='9875425698'

customerId='CI10001';

**ApplicationForm Controller Where I am getting data successfully**

```
class ApplicationForm extends Controller
{
    public function saveApplicationForm(Request $request){
      return $request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code you have tried and where are you facing issue?

Comment: Hi @LeenaPatel thanks for the reply.... actually I need to know how can I achieve above mentioned functionality. I've just created a form and send data into controller.

Comment: I would probably modify the general registration route not to include a password, and then insert a middleware that checks if a password has not been set, and if that's the case, prompt the user to set a password. 
You do want to build-in something that throttles/prevents abuse. Also, you need to handle the situation wherein someone does not set a password for a user (i.e. auto-delete that account or follow-up with e-mails).

Comment: @T.Altena Thanks for your answer.... but can you please provide me the example code for that. you can post your answer below :)

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar try my example you can do what u ask in question

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @JigneshJoisar it works. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add user by submiting form

```
$password = bcrypt('secret'); //add here random password

$user = new User();
$user->email = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$user->mobileNo = '123456789';
$user->customerId = '1245';
$user->password = $password;  
$user->save();
```

after you insert raw on user table login by user id without password

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id,true); // Login and "remember" the given user...
```

by otherwise login with  email and password

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $password], $remember);
```

> all action do in one method(action)

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment:

In the RegisterController (App\Http\Controllers\Auth)

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'institution' => $data['institution'],
        'password' => 'NOT_SET',
    ]);
}
```

Then create a middleware (e.g. php artisan make:middleware Must_have_password)

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Must_have_password
{
    /**
     * Verify if password is set, otherwise redirect to password-set page.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user && $user->password !== 'NOT_SET') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        else return redirect('/set-password');
    }
}
```

Of course, you then need to create a password setting view and hook that to the /set-password route. As I said in the comment, you want to make sure that /set-password route is well protected because you don't want people hijacking accounts that way. The good thing about this approach (using NOT_SET) is that people can always use the password_reset infrastructure to reset their password if they don't do it initially.

This is a bit hacky, but because Laravel always encrypts the passwords, there is no way the value can become NOT_SET in another way. Alternatively, you could add a boolean to your user-model (something like Must_Reset) that redirects to the password-reset page.

You can also hook in the password-reset functionality of Laravel, look for 'One Time Password Laravel' (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474057/laravel-5-4-create-password-on-first-login)).